# How to add timestamp to flowplayer secure streaming plugin (using rtmpe/wowza)

Tags: security, timestamp, token, flowplayer, wowza

I have been searching for the past 2 days to find a solution to this problem so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using a custom token (I recompiled plugin swf) with wowza server at the other end. It works fine but people can still copy our player code and play it on their site by linking to our swf.

I want to implement a timestamp into my secure streaming config. I added a timestamp and added the urlResolvers to the clip part but then my flowplayer gives me an error that it couldn't find the video (the invalid link is with the hash and timestamp).

My question is, if I use the timestamp in my player, what other configuration do I need to do? Do I need to do something to my wowza server? Because clearly, adding the timestamp, the server cant find the video.

Please help me with any info that you have. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The time stamp is used as a security token or to obfuscate the url. all you need to do is

```
// <![CDATA[
  window.onload = function () {
    $f("player", "flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
      plugins: {
        secure: {
          url: "flowplayer.securestreaming-3.2.8.swf",
          timestampUrl: "sectimestamp.php"
        }
      },
      clip: {
        baseUrl: "YOUR BASE URL",
        url: "trailer.flv",
        urlResolvers: "secure",
        scaling: "fit",
        onStart: function (clip) {
          document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = clip.baseUrl + "/" + clip.url;
        }
      }
    });
  };
  // ]]>
  </script>
```

and in your sectimestamp.php it's a very simple line of code:

```
<?php
echo time();
?>
```

then you use it with something like this in a video.php file

```
$hash = $_GET['h'];
$streamname = $_GET['v'];
$timestamp = $_GET['t'];
$current = time();
$token = '12359khlsdfhlasiu3'; // I recommend using a dynamically generated token
$checkhash = md5($token . '/' . $streamname . $timestamp);

if (($current - $timestamp) <= 2 && ($checkhash == $hash)) {
  $fsize = filesize($streamname);
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $streamname . '"');
  if (strrchr($streamname, '.') == '.mp4') {
    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
  } else {
    header('Content-Type: video/x-flv');
  }
  header('Content-Length: ' . $fsize);
  session_cache_limiter('nocache');
  header('Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT');
  header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  $file = fopen($streamname, 'rb');
  print(fread($file, $fsize));
  fclose($file);
  exit;
} else {
  header('Location: /URL/');
}
```

and that's an example of using it in flowplayer